# Computing the Galois goup of $G(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Compute the following Galois group:

$G(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q})$.

I found this problem in a pdf file I was independently reading. It appears to have 8 elements. How would I find these 8 elements? In particular, would someone be able to show me how to do this one? Then I should understand and be able to do the other 9 the pdf provides.

Comment: In this problem, is their a normal field extension?

Answer (score 1):

Field automorphisms can map each root to $\pm\sqrt{2},\pm\sqrt{3},\pm\sqrt{5}$, respectively, so $2$ for each root is $2^3=8$. Note that these are the only automorphisms because $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt n]\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-n)$, which has roots $\pm \sqrt n$.

Comment: That makes sense. Now, how do I know if a Galois group has a normal field extension? In this example, is their one?

Comment: @DanielSmith The phrase "a Galois group has a normal field extension" does not make sense. What do you actually mean?

Comment: "Which of these field extensions are normal field extensions".

Comment: This correctly gives an outer bound for possible automorphisms, but some proof is needed for the fact that all 8 possibilities can really occur.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]\cap\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\mathbb{Q}$, so you could say that their values are "independent" (I feel like I'm failing on the rigor here, feel free to correct me)

Comment: Quick Question. Suppose I had something like $G(\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{4}})/\mathbb{Q})$. Would this Galois group have 4 automorphisms then?

Comment: There's an issue here: $\Bbb Q(5^{1/4})/\Bbb Q$ is not a Galois extension, because the minimal polynomial of $5^{1/4}$ is $x^4 - 5$, but $\Bbb Q(5^{1/4})$ is not its splitting field, so technically speaking $\Bbb Q(5^{1/4})/\Bbb Q$ does not have an associated Galois group, although it does have a group of field automorphisms fixing $\Bbb Q$